# Backbone and Handlebars Rendering View with this.$el.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have started playing with backbone and Handlebars, the code below breaks at `this.$el.html(jsObject);` and gives next error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined tasks.js:26
(anonymous function) tasks.js:26
fire jquery.js:3119
self.fireWith jquery.js:3231
done jquery.js:9275
callback jquery.js:9685
```

There is a done function to allow fetch to comeback before the JSON.parse comes in.  I have used `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` as handlebars wants a JavaScript object and my api returns json (I am sure there is a better way). The `console.log(jsObject);` gives the correct handlebars generated html so not sure why it stops, I did want to do something like `var context = template(jsonObject.toJSON());` as this will work with block data in the code.

Edit: I have cleaned this up to remove `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`, and use toJSON() and put the full error in. Using Backbone 1.1.2 and JQuery v1.11.1.

```
var serverUrl           = 'http://test.local/'; 
var Event = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var EventCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Event,
    url: serverUrl + 'events'   
});

var EventListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#events",
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();              
    },
    render: function () {
        var events = new EventCollection;
        var eventsFetch = events.fetch({
            success : function(data){
                events = ((data));
    //          console.log(events); 
            }       
        });
        eventsFetch.done(function(){
            var template = Handlebars.compile( $("#events-template").html() );
            var rendered = template(events.toJSON());
                console.log(rendered);
            this.$el.html(rendered);
            return this;
        });     
    }
}); 

var EventListView = new EventListView();
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="events"></div>
        <script id="events-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            <table>
                {{#each []}} 
                <tr>
                    <td>{{this.event_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{this.entity_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{this.event_title}}</td>
                    <td>{{this.event_desc}}</td>
                    <td>{{this.event_state}}</td>
                    <td>{{this.id}}</td>
                </tr>
                {{/each}}
            </table>
        </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tasks.js" /></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: still no good. tried '#events' and "#events" and el: 'body'.

Comment: can you provide the html that is in the DOM before you create the view - seems like your element might not exist when you create the view.

Comment: Backbone version 1.1.2

Comment: If I use $(this.el).html I do not get an error but it still does not work and 'this.$el' should work in 1.1.2

Comment: clintronx I have added the html, handlebars is taking the template from the DOM and rendering it correctly `console.log(rendered);` proves this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery.proxy to preserve scope:

> `eventsFetch.done($.proxy(function(){
>     var template = Handlebars.compile( $("#events-template").html() );
>     var rendered = template(events.toJSON());
>     console.log(rendered);
>     this.$el.html(rendered);
>     return this;
>   }, this));`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your `this` reference is incorrectly scoped when your deferred resolves. Try this:

```
var _this = this;
eventsFetch.done(function(){
        var template = Handlebars.compile( $("#events-template").html() );
        var rendered = template(events.toJSON());
            console.log(rendered);
        _this.$el.html(rendered);
        return _this;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks clintronx made my day! anything else you think I can do to make this code better.